# Use-Site variance in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, covariance, contravariance, generic-variance

```
open class A
class B: A()

fun <T> copy(src: MutableList<T>, dst: MutableList<T>) {
    for (i in 0 until src.size) {
        dst.add(i, src[i])
    }
}
```

For the above mentioned code I understand that `copy function` expects both type parameters of **exactly same type**. With a slight modification `copy(src: MutableList<T>, dst: MutableList<in T>)` notice the **in** keyword, I am saying that `src` **must be of exactly type `T`** but destination can be of `type T` or **any super type of T**.

For the above modified code, I am able to call the method as following,

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val l1 = mutableListOf(B(), B())
    val l2 = mutableListOf<A>()
    copy(l1, l2)
} // main
```

The above **`copy(l1, l2)`** does not work if I remove **`in`** from the destination (understood).

My question is, I am able to call the function without any error **if update the function parameter `src` to accept `out` projection of the list**. e.g.

```
fun <T> copy(src: MutableList<out /*notice out here*/ T>, dst: MutableList<T>) {
    for (i in 0 until src.size) {
        dst.add(i, src[i])
    }
}
```

***In this case, I am not able to understand what goes on under the hood.Can any one explain please?***

Note that this is just an example from the book. I know I can use `List` instead of immutable list in `src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`out` here works symmetrically to `in`:

> in keyword, I am saying that src must be of exactly type T but destination can be of type T or any super type of T

So now you are saying that `src` must be a `MutableList` of type `T` or any subtype of `T`, while `dst` must be a `MutableList` of exactly type `T`.

So when you have `l1: MutableList<B>` and `l2: MutableList<A>`, the compiler infers the type parameter in `copy(l1, l2)` as `copy<A>(l1, l2)`, and it typechecks: `MutableList<B>` is a subtype of `MutableList<out A>`.

Because you are only using `out`-compatible operations on `src`, and only `in`-compatible operations on `dst`, as @s1m0nw1 says it makes perfect sense to include both modifiers.

Answer (score 6):

since you're using the function in only one way you should use the use-site variance modifiers anyways to make it clear to the caller that you may add to `dst` and get data from `src`:

```
fun <T> copy(src: MutableList<out T>, dst: MutableList<in T>) {
    for (i in 0 until src.size) {
        dst.add(i, src[i])
    }
}
```

Further, since `src` is really used as a `List` rather than a `MutableList`, you should prefer it accordingly. As a result, you won't need the `out` modifier anymore since `List` already defined its type parameter `T` as `out` only:

```
fun <T> copy(src: List<T>, dst: MutableList<in T>)
```

In response to your question: The problem actually happens when you call `copy` with two differently typed lists in your main, once with `MutableList<A>` and once with `MutableList<B>`. The compiler cannot infer whether the type of `copy` shall be `A` or `B`.  To fix this, you need to give more information:

1) When you set `dst` to `MutableList<in T>`, the compiler knows that you will only add `T` types based on `src` to it (in your example this is `B`).

2) When you set `src` to `MutableList<out T>`, the compiler understands that you will only add `T` and its subtypes to `dst` which is fine as well (in this case `T` will be inferred as `A` though).

Comment: Agree with everything in @s1m0nw1's answer above. Something that you might find useful is reading the [official documentation page about generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html), and notice their distinction between **producers** and **consumers**.  Basically, something marked `out` is produced (hence immutable list use `out`, as they only produce values, not consume them); something marked `in` is consumed.

Comment: Thanks @s1m0nw1. `in this case T will be inferred as A though` got it now.